# Find the matrices of the linear mappings in the following bases

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find the matrices of the linear mappings in the following bases

$F(x,y,z) = (x-y+z, x+y-z)$

$\{(1,1,1), (1,0,0), (0,0,1)\}$ and $\{(1,2), (3,3)\}$

I don't really know how to start this task. It is a bit confusing for me as there is 2nd to 3d. Thanks for help

Comment: Quick: apply $\;F\;$ to each of the vectors in the leftmost basis and write down the result as a linear combination of the rightmost basis. The resulting coefficients will be **the columns** of your matrix...

Comment: Right, I have done it and I got a result 

\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1/3\end{bmatrix}

However there is word "matrices". So shouldn't we find 2 of them? One for left-sided basis and one for-right sided one?

Comment: It should say matrix and linear mapping in singular, and you should get a $2\times  3$ matrix, see my answer below. If it is still unclear I can elaborate a bit more

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to find the matrix representation in a more general setting. Suppose we have a linear transformation $T: V\to W$ where the domain and codomain are vector spaces. Suppose $V$ has a basis $\mathcal{B}=(v_1,\ldots, v_n)$ and $W$ has a basis $\mathcal{B}'=(w_1,\ldots, w_m)$. The matrix representation of $T$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ is an $m\times n$ matrix. To find the entries of the $j^{th}$ column, for $1\le j \le n$, we take the (unique) expression
$$T(v_j)=\sum_{i=1}^m a_{ij}w_i.$$
Then, the $j^{th}$ column of the matrix representation $\mathcal{M}(T,\mathcal{B}, \mathcal{B'})$ is 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
a_{1j}\\
\vdots\\
a_{mj}
\end{bmatrix}$$
Let's apply this procedure to our current situation. Let's label $$v_1=(1,1,1), v_2=(1,0,0), v_3=(0,0,1)$$
and 
$$w_1=(1,2), w_2=(3,3).$$ 
We have a linear transformation given by 
$$F(x,y,z)=(x-y+z,x+y-z) $$
Then 
$$F(v_1)=F(1,1,1)=(1,1)=\frac{1}{3}w_2$$
$$ F(v_2)=F(1,0,0)=(1,1)=\frac{1}{3}w_2$$
$$ F(v_3)=F(0,0,1)=(1,-1)=w_2-2w_1.$$
So, our matrix is 
$$ \mathcal{M}(F,\mathcal{B},\mathcal{B}')=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&-2\\
\frac{1}{3}&\frac{1}{3}&1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Ahh! I got this answer a few seconds ago and I came here to ask if it is correct one. Thank you! I have one more question:  
I have spotted 2 similar types of tasks connected with basis  
1) This one from this post  
2) Assuming that A is the matrix of a linear operator F in S find the matrix B of F in R. 
What is the difference?

Comment: What are $S$ and $R$? Bases?

Comment: http://www.mini.pw.edu.pl/~tomtracz/alg/set_12.pdf
It's task 1) on this page.

Comment: I think what the instructor wants you to do is write an element of $R$ in terms of the elements of $S$, then apply $A$ to it, and use that to make the matrix representation as I showed above.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the matrix associated to a linear map between vector spaces with two given bases is the matrix that has for columns the images of the vectors of the first basis expressed in terms of the second basis. Hence, a linear map from an $n$ dimensional vector space to an $m$ dimensional vector space will have a matrix with $n$ columns (one for each basis element in the source vector space) and $m$ rows (one for each coefficient needed to express the image of a vector in terms of the basis of the target vector space).

So in your case you will get a $2\times 3$ matrix whose first column is the vector $F(1,1,1)$ expressed in terms of the basis $\{ (1,2),(3,3) \}$, and so on.